# Android instrumentation test dexing error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dex, android-databinding

I am trying to do some instrumentation tests with Espresso, but when I am compiling my test, gradle make return an error:

> Error:Gradle: Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/databinding/DataBindingComponent;

I assumed that there was some dependency errors and listed dependencies like this:
`.\gradlew app:dependencies`

And there was the strange thing: I am using databinding version 1.0-rc4, but in the listed dependencies there was 1.0-rc3:

```
default - Configuration for default artifacts.
+--- com.android.databinding:library:1.0-rc3                                     
|    +--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:1.0-rc3
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 23.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
+--- com.android.databinding:adapters:1.0-rc3
|    \--- com.android.databinding:library:1.0-rc3 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0    
|    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
\--- com.trello:rxlifecycle-components:0.4.0
     +--- com.trello:rxlifecycle:0.4.0
     |    +--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.3.0
     |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0 -> 23.1.1
     |    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14 -> 1.0.16
     |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.16
     +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 (*)
     \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.16 

provided - Classpath for only compiling the main sources.
+--- com.android.databinding:compiler:1.0-rc4                                     
|    \--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:1.0-rc4
\--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
```

Where did this 1.0-rc3 come from? There is no such string "rc3" in my whole project (except in generated dex-cache files).

**UPD:**
I think this is an android gradle-plugin issue, because same code works with gradle 1.5 but fails with gradle 2.0.0-beta2 and 2.0.0-beta4. 
**UPD2:**
Solved the problem. 
Project was relatively old and `android-databinding` plugin grown from beta since `gradle 1.5.0-beta1`
Now to enable databinding you should only add

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

in your `android{}` section.
So if you face such problem, make sure you deleted these strings from your `build.gradle` files: 
1) `apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'`
2) `classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4'`
3) `apt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:1.0-rc4'`

Comment: Perhaps add your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem. 
Project was relatively old and `android-databinding` plugin grown from beta since `gradle 1.5.0-beta1`
Now to enable databinding you should only add

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

in your `android{}` section.
So if you face such problem, make sure you deleted these strings from your `build.gradle` files: 
1) `apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'`
2) `classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4'`
3) `apt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:1.0-rc4'`